# How do I refresh an oauth2 access token for quickbooks with node.js?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, quickbooks

I am writing a script in node.js to build invoices automatically in Quickbooks. I am using the node-quickbooks library for connecting to Quickbooks and everything works great except that I have to get the access token and refresh token from the quickbooks oauth playground every time the access token expires (every hour). I am looking for some help in figuring out how to refresh the access token automatically so I don't have to do this manually anymore.

```
const QuickBooks = require("node-quickbooks");

const clientId = "";
const clientSecret = "";
const redirectUri = "";
const realmId = "";

var accessToken = "";
var refreshToken = "";

var qbo = new QuickBooks(clientId,      // consumer key
                         clientSecret,  // consumer secret
                         accessToken,
                         false,         // no token secret for oAuth 2.0
                         realmId,
                         true,          // use the sandbox?
                         true,          // enable debugging?
                         null,          // set minorversion, or null for the latest version
                         "2.0",         // oAuth version
                         refreshToken
);

const quickbooksID = "59";

qbo.getCustomer(quickbooksID, (err, customer) => { // get id
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else qbo.getItem('19', (err, item) => {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        else qbo.createInvoice({
            "Line": [
                {
                "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
                "Amount": 32.0,
                "SalesItemLineDetail": {
                    "ItemRef": {
                        "name": item.Name, // qbo.getItem()
                        "value": item.Id
                    },
                    "Qty": 5.0
                }
                }
            ],
            "CustomerRef": {
                "value": customer.Id,
                "name": customer.DisplayName
            }
            }, (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            })
    })
})
```

I've removed the client secrets and stuff like that for privacy reasons, rest assured they're there. I would really appreciate any help with this at all. TIA!

Here's the specific error code if that helps:

```
"error": [
      {
        "message": "message=AuthenticationFailed; errorCode=003200; statusCode=401",
        "detail": "Token expired: AB01632845164r8NbakMicxhIqC9mf69lzQMX907r73MtGTdT7",
        "code": "3200",
        "element": null
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the `ituit-oauth` package to handle updating your access_token. I am using the combination of both packages. One for auth and the other for api calls.

Comment: @creedjarrett Thanks, this is helpful.  My brain is struggling with the flow.  Where and when do I verify if the token is expired and send the refresh?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?  I'm trying to figure out how to determine that the token is expired and then how to refresh it.   Thanks!

Comment: @ShannonCole i typically verify that the token is still valid (by checking that the current time is before the expiry), before I make any quickbooks calls. If it is valid, then I proceed with the quickbooks operations. If it is not valid, then I refresh the token, then proceed with the quickbooks call.

Comment: @ShannonCole the `intuit-oath` lib provides everything you need for refreshing the token with the `refreshUsingToken` method which accepts the refresh token and passes back a valid access token. I also calculate the time (in milliseconds) when the token will expire and save that to the db with the token so I know when I will need to refresh it.

Comment: Great, thanks. I was attempting to make the call, get the expired message, refresh, and then make the call again.  It didn’t feel like the best approach. I like your approach too.  The node-QuickBooks had a built in function to refresh the token too that updates itself.  It’s not listed in the package but built in.